# Change ios_base of open FILE from 'out' to 'app' without closing the FILE

Tags: c++, io

Is it possible in C++ to change the output mode of an open `FILE*` without closing and reopening it?
I have a `FILE*` opened in mode `std::ios_base::out` and would like to switch to `std::ios_base::app` in a more elegant way.

Comment: what is it that you are hoping to achieve? `::out` opens the file for writing, and `::app` opens the file for writing at the end of the file. If you already have the file open as `::out`, couldn't you just `fseek` to the end of the file and start writing?

Comment: @DavidHope `::app` always writes at then end of the file, so it's not exactly the same behavior as `::out`, but I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write at the end of the file, simply seek to the end of the file, it's the easier solution.

On POSIX system (including linux, unix, ...) and most likely on Windows too, it is not possible to change the open mode of a file once it has been openned. Thus you have to close it and reopen it.

If your operating system has some particularities which permit this and you don't care about portability, you can achieve this by using the right system call in a `std::filebuf` subclass, then creating your own `std::fstream` subclass.